# Image not centering in SVG arc (HTML)

Tags: html, svg

The background picture is not centering behind my SVG circle arc. You can see the image: [image: here]

I want something like this:

[image: here]

obviously without the red cut part.

My HTML is as follows:

```
    <svg width="200" height="200">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="image"  x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
            <image x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="Assets/Images/RoundSlider.png"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(100,100)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
        <path d="M 0 0 -70 70 A 99 99 0 1 0 -70 -70 Z" fill="url(#image)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your path's bounding box actually starts more on the right than if it were a full circle:

```js
const bbox = document.querySelector('path').getBBox();
const rect = document.querySelector('rect');
rect.setAttribute('x', bbox.x);
rect.setAttribute('y', bbox.y);
rect.setAttribute('width', bbox.width);
rect.setAttribute('height', bbox.height);
```

```html
<h3>The red rectangle represents your &lt;path> BBox.</h3>
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <g transform="translate(100,100)" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none">
    <path d="M 0 0 -70 70 A 99 99 0 1 0 -70 -70 Z"/>
    <rect stroke="red"/>
    <circle stroke="green" r="100" cx="0" cy="0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

So you can simply adjust your image's `x` attribute so it takes this offset into account (assuming you got a square image):

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" width="1" height="1">
      <!--
        #mypath.getBBox().x = -70
        Add 100 from translate(100, 100)
        and we got our 30 units offset
      -->
      <image x="-30" y="0" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Clock-green.png"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(100,100)" stroke="red" stroke-width="2">
    <path id="mypath" d="M 0 0 -70 70 A 99 99 0 1 0 -70 -70 Z" fill="url(#image)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Or you could also just display this <image> and clip it (might be easier with more complex pathes):

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myclip">
      <use xlink:href="#mypath"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Clock-green.png" clip-path="url(#myclip)"/>
  <path id="mypath" d="M 0 0 -70 70 A 99 99 0 1 0 -70 -70 Z" fill="transparent" transform="translate(100,100)" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```